# MSN WEATHER API

Tags: api, weather, msn

I am using MSN WEATHER API to create a website for a school project. I get weather informations using this link example: http://weather.service.msn.com/data.aspx?weadegreetype=F&culture=en-US&weasearchstr=Chicago,IL

Now I create the report of the website and I need to write some more informations about MSN Weather API. but I can't find anything.

I just search on all internet but I can't find a page about MSN WEATHER API.

Answer (score 5):

We are writing to notify you that the Microsoft Weather API will no longer be available for download and will be discontinued as of April 15, 2015, meaning it will no longer provide weather data.  Accordingly, please remove the Microsoft Weather API from any of your products or apps that currently use it.

Here is a list of external providers who might be able to support your needs if you are interested in obtaining an alternate weather API:

```
http://api.accuweather.com/ 
http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/pricing.html 
https://developer.forecast.io/
```

Disclaimer:  Microsoft and Microsoft Weather are not affiliated or associated with any of the above companies in any way.

Thank You 
Microsoft Weather Team

Comment: Thx. for extra links

Comment: Seems still active